# trigger a list item on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to load the `#panelInfo` list item on page load. What am I missing?

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
        <a class="hidden-md hidden-lg" href="#2dTab" aria-controls="2Dtab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> Map</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="active hidden-md hidden-lg" href="#3dTab" aria-controls="3Dtab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> Scene</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a role="button"  data-target="#panelInfo" aria-haspopup="true">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
            Info
        </a>
    </li>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dropdown-menu li:nth-child(3)').click();
    console.log('CLICKED');
});
```

Comment: `$('#dropdown-menu li:nth-child(3)').trigger('click');`?

Comment: no, that didnt work either.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling click() on a LI element, try this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dropdown-menu li:nth-child(3) a')[0].trigger('click');
    console.log('CLICKED');
});
```

Comment: it threw a typeError "trigger" undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can use the data-target attribute to trigger a click.

```js
$('.dropdown-menu a[data-target="#panelInfo"]').trigger('click');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li>
    <a class="hidden-md hidden-lg" href="#2dTab" aria-controls="2Dtab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> Map</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="active hidden-md hidden-lg" href="#3dTab" aria-controls="3Dtab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> Scene</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a role="button" data-target="#panelInfo" aria-haspopup="true">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> Info
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```